# Multiple choice for table list in ArcGIS Survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I am working with ArcGIS Survey123 appearance. I want the question to be listed as in table form and user able to select multiple answer

[image]

I been trying to create something similar to the above in ArcGIS Survey however I ending with something like. I am not sure why

[image]

However documentation did state: The **table-list appearance** does not support **select_multiple questions** and does not support media in choice lists.

So does this mean it is some sort of limitation?